# Callback timing

Tags: java, android, callback

Hey everyone happy upcoming turkey day !. So I am trying to implement a search manager class that handles all searching for this android app using a parse backend and ran into an interesting problem. Here is the method that should call the search managers search function

```
public void SearchForLostItems(){

    String searchtext = mSearchView.getQuery().toString();

    List<ParseObject> foundposts =  mSearchManager.BasicSearch(searchtext);



        //if we found a matching post go to the post details
                if(parseObjects != null){

                    //Try to get our found posts count if there is more than one match than list them for the user and let them browse
                    try {

                        //if there is only one match then go ahead to the post
                        if(parseObjects.size() == 1){

                            ParseObject foundpost = parseObjects.get(0);

                            Post post = new Post(foundpost.getObjectId(), "");

                            GoToFoundPost(post);
                        }

                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

}
```

And here is the implementation in search manager

```
//Basic search for when someone searches by text, should accept some search text and returhn amatched list of parse objects
public List<ParseObject>BasicSearch(String searchtext){

    final List<ParseObject> PostsHolder = null;

    //Do a search for all posts that contain the search text
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> foundposts = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_POSTS); // get the whole class

    foundposts.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.POST_TITLE,searchtext); // filter the results based on the search text

     foundposts.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() { //call the find in background routine to convert the results to a list
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {

            if(e == null){
                PostsHolder.addAll(parseObjects);
                Log.d("Posts Added", "true");

            }
            else
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
```

return PostsHolder;

}

I think this issue is because the function returns before the callback is complete but I am not sure for java and specifically android.

As always thanks for all the help !

Comment: The first code block is broken, it contains more closing brackets than opening brackets. What's the problem? An exception? We can only guess, because you didn't tell us.

Comment: And what's the turkey day thing about?

Comment: The first code block is a copy paste error the code runs fine, the problem is when stepping through the return statement return PostsHolder; is hit before the callback is done thus PostsHolder is  empty. Mostly I was looking for some clarification on how to force my function to wait until the callback is complete before returning any results, sorry for the confusion.  Turkey day = thanksgiving as its coming up this week.

Comment: Then why don't you fix the copy paste error?

Comment: The error is not really relevant to the question